# Generating limited amount of random numbers in Perl for a known range

Tags: arrays, string, perl, random, range

I have a file `letters.txt` which has couple letters

```
@string1 10 letters

A H K Y M H O L H L

@string2 9 letters

H N U P W X L Y H
```

I am trying to create a file which will have random numbers from 20 to 60 for each letter, for each string.

My expected output should look like :

#### output.txt:

```
@string1

29 27 56 43 39 40 36 48 59 38

@sting2

26 36 39 39 26 51 38 42 42
```

I have tried the code below with `$minimum` as 20 and `$maximum` as 60:

```
open ($fh, '>', $fileToLocate) or die;

my $x = $minimum + int(rand($maximum - $minimum);

print $fh "$x\n";

close $fh;
```

It creates only one random number in `$fileToLocate` file.

I want to extract the number of letters in each string — written just before `letters` in the input file: 10 for `@string1` and 9 for `@string2`

I have tried to this code to create 30 random numbers ranging between 20 and 60, however it did not work out

```
my @Chars = ( 20 .. 60);

$RandString = join("", @Chars[ map { $x } ( 1 .. 30 ) ]);

print $fh "$RandString\n";

close $fh;
```

Comment: *"it did not work out"* doesn't provide any information. What is wrong with what you have written, and what output did you expect?

Comment: It did not create a file, not even with single number within it. My expectation was to have a file which has 30 different/same numbers ranging between 20 to 60 in $RandString and to have this in $fh as my output.

Comment: Well, no. I still do not have an output but thank you for sharing what I should do later on in here. Good to learn.

Comment: And what is `$x`?

Comment: `$x` is the random number that I want to create within min and max range. Then I intended to keep it as creating 1 random number, combining with `map` to create as many as I need for each string. It is like, to say to create 1 random number with `$x`, and then asking it to repeat it n times. (n= length of the string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close.

The code to pick a random number from `$min` to `$max` looks like this.

```
my $rand = $min + int rand($max - $min + 1));
```

So you had that part right, but with an off-by-one error (I made the same mistake earlier). Because `rand` starts at 0, `int rand $x` will go from 0 to `$x - 1`.

Then you need to generate a bunch of them. You're close with the map, but `$x` only stores a single random number, so `map { $x } ( 1 .. 30 )` will just give you one number repeated 30 times. Instead you need to get a new random number inside the map block.

```
my @rands = map { $min + int rand($max - $min + 1)) } 1..length $string;
```

That will run `int($x + rand($y-$x))` for a number of times equal to the number of characters in `$string` and put them all into the list `@rands`. Then you can join `@rands` like you have already.

```
print $fh join '', @rands;
```

That should get you the rest of the way.

Comment: *"You're close"*?

Comment: The code to pick a random number from `$min` to `$max` *actually* looks like this: `my $pick = int rand ($max - $min + 1) + $min`. `int($min + rand($max-$min))` will never result in a value of `$max`.

Comment: @Borodin Right, off-by-one error. `rand` starts at 0. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the answer Schwern. For the last part of the code, when I write as `print $fh join ' ', @rands`; it says that I am having a syntax error. When I put parenthesis after print as :  `print ($fh join ' ', @rands); ` it takes print as a function and still does not create anything. Can you maybe show me where the typo is? I also used `push @rands, $fh;` , but it says I am still having the syntax error.

Comment: At the moment, my code is below and saying that there is a syntax error that I cannot see around `print` -->  `open ($fh, '>', $fileToLocate) or die; my $rand = $minimum + int rand($maximum - $minimum + 1);
   my @rands = map { $minimum + int rand($maximum - $minimum + 1) } 1..5 # $string; 1..5  
    print $fh join ('', @rands);
  close $fh;}`

Comment: @podedo What's that extra `1..5` doing? That's a syntax error.

Comment: @Schwern, i just wanted to try it 5 times, since I dont know how to extract the lenghts of the strings at the moment.

Comment: @podedo `length $string`. You seem to be struggling with basic Perl syntax (not that I blame you). You might need to take a moment and read a Perl book. [Modern Perl](http://modernperlbooks.com/books/modern_perl_2016/) if you already know how to program, [Beginning Perl](https://www.perl.org/books/beginning-perl/) if you don't.

Comment: @Schwern Thank you for sharing. I think I do too. I will give it a try.